# What's the fastest way to send 1000 2MB's files using Python?

Tags: python, upload, flask, rabbitmq, tornado

we have a problem with sending in most efficient way about 1000 (or even more) 2MB's chunks via network. We want to avoid pure sockets (if it won't be possible we will use them). For now we've tested:

1. List item rabbitmq client -> server: about 39sec/GB on localhost (very slow)
2. requests client -> flask server : still about 40sec/GB on localhost
3. flask on tornado with creating threads for each IO write opperation and still 40 sec/GB of SSD flash drive
4. raw tornado still 40 sec/GB

We are running out of ideas. Best solution for us is to use lightweight solution, maybe http.

Comment: Whats your network's upload/download rate?

Comment: It sounds like every method you've tried works at 200 Mbps (25 MB/s). Is that not the transfer rate you expect?

Comment: Well it's seems like it could be my Mac machine issue. 25 MB/s on SSD on localhost is in my opinion slow.

Comment: What do you get with copy and paste in Finder? You'd hope quite a lot more, but it's worth checking before blaming Python or the loopback socket.

Comment: 100 MB cp time:
real 0m1.115s
user 0m0.001s
sys 0m0.094s

Comment: Ok we started to profile third method flask over tornado and realized that most time consuming methods are _iter_basic_lines and make_line_iter from Werkzeug.wsgi. For single upload these methods are called 11k times each (!!!). Any idea how to switch to something more efficient for file uploads?

Answer (score 0):

If all the files are available at the start. I would zip them first to a single file. It is not about the compression but the number of files.
There are certain IO operations (open/close and network start/end) that will happen 100 times for each file which you can easily avoid. Compression will help too.

Now sockets or HTTP, it wont matter much if you have single file (or technically a stream).